# How to understand the convention on describing the "position" of mathematical objects

Tags: soft-question, terminology

When studying algebra, I find that it seems like a convention that we use positional words like *on*, *under*, *over* etc. to describe relations between things. For example:

> $V$ is a vector space **over** $F$.

> $G$ is a group **under** multiplication.

> the operation **on** $G$ is defined by the usual addition.

Positional words are also used in other situations, for example we say:

> Analysis **on** complex manifolds.

My observation is that such convention prefer to put structures/objects/operations on top of the (in some sense "more basic") things what define them.

To me, they are somewhat natural to say. But as I'm not a naive speaker, they are still pretty vague, for example, why we choose to say *vector space over field* and *operation on set* but not the other way around.

So, may I ask for the precise reasons why we "visualize" them as such?

Comment: This certainly is not precise but here goes it! I think vector space over a field is most clearly seen in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is a vector space over the reals and since it contains a copy of the reals I visualize it as hovering over the reals. Acting on a set or on a manifold I think makes sense to me because the word on is literally describing the precise location of the action. For the under part I guess I like to think of the fact that without the operation, G would just be a mere set. G becomes a group under the power of the operation, kind of like a queen or king.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I agree they are pretty vague. I don't see a clear reason why these particular prepositions should be used in these examples. I don't think of these prepositions as suggesting any positional relationships here.

Comment: Do you know the corresponding mathematical expressions in your native language, and in what way are they different?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I'm pretty sure that my native language uses literal translation, so  they feel the same for me. In that sense, I agree that those "positional" words are rather idioms than jargons

Answer (score 7):

Although each preposition has a core meaning or set of (generally closely related) core meanings, prepositional usage is highly idiomatic, and not just in English: this is true in general. Once you get away from those core meanings, choice of preposition is largely a matter of idiom.

For instance, there is no outstandingly obvious choice of preposition to express the relationship between a group and its operation; the use of *under*, as in *a group under multiplication*, is simply idiomatic. It makes some intuitive sense if we think of the operation as something imposed **on** the **under**lying set, but one could make cases for other ways of thinking about the relationship.

Some of these idioms are already present in non-mathematical language. For instance, it is entirely idiomatic to speak of operating **on** or performing operations **on** things in general; to speak of addition, say, as an operation **on** the real numbers is just an instance of this existing idiom. In other cases a mathematical prepositional usage may not have clear non-mathematical parallels, and there may be no way to tell how it got started; presumably someone started using it, others picked it up, and it eventually became a standard idiom.

Answer (score 3):

As in many languages, prepositions in English are a complete mess for non-native speakers. Any given preposition can have many different meanings (and the groupings of these meanings varies from language to language).

So my best answer to your question is that, while "over", "under", and "on" *can* all refer to positional relationships, they *don't necessarily* refer to positional relationships. Here are a few examples of many different usages of ["over"](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/how-use-over), ["under"](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/under), and ["on"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/on_1). To me, the following example sentences from those links come closer to how these prepositions are used in mathematics than interpreting them as positional:

- "There was a lot of discussion *over* who should get the job." *(connected with)*
- "Children will educate themselves *under* [the] right conditions." *(an aspect of)*
- "We lived *on* an estate." *(in a setting)*